# Art : A Particular Mirror

Tags: optics, reflection

There is a particular mirror used here (1 minute 26 seconds) in  [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5YSV0AqZ-_4), which reflects light in a way I've never seen. I was hoping maybe one of you might know what kind of mirror this is, so that I may use it for my own personal use.

Comment: Not available in India. Please see  if you can provide it somehow.

Comment: Video not available anymore. (Germany)

Comment: This is what I got as well:"The uploader has not made this video available in your country."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe it is a concave spherical mirror that is *very* delicately made. It is possible it is not a glass mirror but a more pure material. Notice that the outside is very bright: this is necessary to achieve such a projection from a mirror.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a concave bathroom mirror, the same kind that gives you a magnified image of your face. Any concave mirror would work like this with varying degrees of image quality.